# Using Postgres log_min_duration_statement, but I want to exclude the binds

Tags: postgresql

We are using log_min_duration_statement to capture long-running Postgres queries into the log. However, the log entries include the bind variables, which can become quite lengthy (> 50 MB) and cause problems parsing the logfile as a foreign table.

And I'm sure some shops would not want possibly-sensitive bind variables showing up in the log, although that is not yet an issue for us.

Is there a way to capture the queries, but without the bind variable values? We are using Postgres 14.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, but you could set `log_parameter_max_length` to 0 to log no parameters whatsoever. That is not appealing, however, because parameters are important information.

Comment: This looks like a great solution to my problem. Thank you!

Comment: This parameter did not make a difference for my use case. I believe that is because the problem data being logged is actually presented as literals within the SQL statement, not as true bind variables.

Comment: I assume you might have looked into this, but this sounds like a good use case for pg_stat_statements (which replaces literals in the query text with bind-like parameter references), with the main downside being that you'd have to query that using SQL and not knowing the exact execution timestamp, instead of getting it output into the logs.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress the parameter list in the log file by setting the parameter [`log_parameter_max_length`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-PARAMETER-MAX-LENGTH) to 0. This is usually not a good idea, as parameters are valuable information, but it may be just what you need here.

In your comment you say that that doesn't seem to work for you, since "the problem data being logged is actually presented as literals within the SQL statement"- I assume that you are using the JDBC driver (because of the many `BIND` messages), and because the JDBC driver substitutes the parameters into the statement during the first five execution of a `java.sql.PreparedStatement`. You can force the JDBC driver to use a server side prepared statement immediately by setting [`prepareThreshold`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/server-prepare/#example93using-server-side-prepared-statements) to 1. This can conveniently be set as an option in the connection string.